# Условие SQL, если поле равно NULL()

Tags: sql, mysql

Есть такой **SELECT**:

sum(if(IdLikeType=1,1,0)) as pozitive, sum(if(IdLikeType=0,1,0)) as negative

Как сделать, чтобы в случае IdLikeType = 0 или Null, в pozitive заносился 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)?

Answer (score 0):

У тебя и так в случае, если IdLikeType не равен 1, то заносится 0.

Если же 0 нужен, только в случае если IdLikeType равен 0 или Null, то можно так:
2 - во всех остальных случаях.

sum(
CASE
  WHEN IdLikeType = 1 THEN 1
  WHEN (IdLikeType = 0 OR IdLikeType IS NULL) THEN 0
  ELSE 2
END
) as pozitive

Comment: Сейчас запрос возвращает :

     array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#174 (2) { ["pozitive"]=> NULL      ["negative"]=> NULL } }

Не срабатывает: "У тебя и так в случае, если IdLikeType не равен 1, то заносится 0."

Comment: А так?

sum( CASE WHEN IdLikeType = 1 THEN 1 WHEN (IdLikeType = 0 OR IdLikeType IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) as pozitive